# How to bind two function for a button click in reactjs

Tags: events, reactjs

How can I achieve the below scenario in ReactJS?

```
function foo1(){
    console.log('foo1')
}

function foo2(){
    console.log('foo2')
}
$('#button').click(foo1);
$('#button').click(foo2);
```

I want both the functions to be called on clicking the button

Consider the below jsx code

```
 Var Component = React.createClass({
    foo1: function(){
        console.log('foo1');
    },
    foo2: function(){
        console.log('foo2');
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
           <button onClick={this.foo}> click me </button>
        );
    }

});
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can write a third function to call the first two sequentially:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    foo1: function(){
        console.log('foo1');
    },
    foo2: function(){
        console.log('foo2');
    },
    foo: function(){
        foo1();
        foo2();
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
           <button onClick={this.foo}> click me </button>
        );
    }

});
```

or make it inline:

```
<button onClick={function(){ this.foo1(); this.foo2(); }.bind(this)}> click me </button>
```

Comment: Or, `onClick={this.foo.bind(null, this.foo1, this.foo2)}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of functions, and iterate over it.

```
Var Component = React.createClass({
foo1: function(){
    console.log('foo1');
},
foo2: function(){
    console.log('foo2');
},
render: function(){
    return (
       <button onClick={(e)=> [foo1, foo2].forEach(x=> x.call(null,e))}> click me </button>
    );
}
```

});